# Riemann integrability of indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the indicator function $I_A(x)$ of $A$, where $A=\{x \in [0,1] : x\text{ has a base-3 expansion containing a 1} \}$.

**Is $f$ Riemann integrable?**

It would seem I need to establish whether the elements of $A$ and $[0,1]-A$ are dense in $[0,1]$?

Comment: The set $A^c$ is the celebrated Cantor set, which has Lebesgue measure $0$. Therefore, ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lebesgue integrability, i was looking for an answer using only upper riemann sums etc.

Comment: There is a theorem states that $f$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if the set of its discontinuities has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: For the proof, check [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Theorem) link.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I think OP means he doesn't know measure theory at all.

Comment: @Mark I just think this is the most direct approach to attack the problem. In my opinion, it might be difficult to solve this problem without touching anything about the "length" (i.e., measure) of $A$ or $A^c$. Of course, I am happy to see an elementary proof.

Comment: @Zhanxiong - $A^c$ is not quite the Cantor set, since  in base 3, $0.222... = 1$. However, the intersection of $A$ and the Cantor set is only countable.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Cantor set does contain 1 and $1 \in A^c$, right?

Comment: @Zhanxiong - every end point of an interval in the Cantor set construction will also be in $A$. These are exactly the numbers with two trinary expansions, one of which has no $1$s.

Comment: @Zhanxiong - Just to be clear, $A^c$ is a subset of the Cantor set, and therefore also has measure $0$. Thus everything else you said is completely correct. I am just pointing out a minor technical deficiency.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see your point. Maybe you should tell me $2/3 = 0.122\ldots \in C \cap A$. Yes, a rigorous statement is $C = \bar{A^c}$, the closure of $A^c$. And the proof can goes like $\lambda(A^c) \leq \lambda(\bar{A^c}) = \lambda(C) = 0$.

Comment: One minor correction to what I've said above. Not *every* endpoint of the intervals in the construction of the Cantor set is also in $A$. There is a sole exception: $0$ is in the Cantor set, but not in $A$. All the other endpoints (numbers of the form $\dfrac n{3^m}$) are in both sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't that hard to show from the definition of the Riemann integral - well, not hard as compared to doing anything directly from the definition, which is a rather high point of comparison.

I don't know which definition of the Riemann integral you are working with. The one that makes this simplest is that $\int_a^b g(t)\,dt = L$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P$ such that for every refinement $P'$ of $P$, the Upper and Lower Riemann sums of $g$ over $P'$ are within $\epsilon$ of $L$.

The first thing to note is that for *any* partition of $[0,1]$, the upper Riemann sum of $f$ is $\le 1$ (in fact, it is $=1$, but we don't need that). On the other hand, if $P'$ is a refinement of $P$, then the lower sum $L(f, P') \ge L(f,P)$.

So it will follow that $\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt = 1$ if we can show the existence of partitions $P_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} L(f,P_n) = 1$. For that, let $$P_n = \left\{\dfrac m{3^n}\mid m \in \Bbb N, m \le 3^n\right\}$$
What is important about these partitions is that on each of the intervals $\left[\frac m{3^n}, \frac {m+1}{3^n}\right]$, *the first $n$ trits ("trinary digits") to the right of the radix ("decimal point") in the trinary expansions do not change*. (Note that the partition points other than $0$ are exactly the numbers with two trinary expansions, one of which agrees with the lower interval, the other of which agrees with the upper interval.) So if there is a $1$ trit in those first $n$, the entire interval will be in $A$, so $f = 1$ on the interval. Therefore the lower Riemann sum over such intervals will be the sum of the interval widths. The intervals of $P_n$ that do not have a $1$ in the first $n$ trits will all contain at least one point with no $1$ trits in their expansion, so the lower sum over them will be $0$. Thus the lower Riemann sum over the entire partition will be the sum of the widths of the intervals with a $1$ in the first $n$ trits.

$\frac 23$ of the intervals will not have a $1$ as their first trit. And $\frac 23$ of those will also not have a $1$ as their second trit, and so on. In the end, $\left(\frac 23\right)^n$ of the $3^n$ intervals in $P_n$, or $2^n$ total, have no $1$s anywhere in the first $n$ trits. Since each interval has width $\frac 1{3^n}$, the total width of those intervals is $\left(\frac 23\right)^n$, and the total widths of the intervals with a $1$ trit is therefore $1-\left(\frac 23\right)^n$. That is,
$$L(f,P_n) = 1-\left(\frac 23\right)^n$$

Clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty} L(f,P_n) = 1$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Nice answer …..